# Block the "drupal" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-blacklist-request

On a site about Drupal, [drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal) doesn't have any meaning.
The tag is used on SO questions, but when the question is migrated on drupal.SE, it should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed.  We do have a concept of a tag that could be applied to *every* question on the site and gets stripped on a migration.

I guess it makes sense for `drupal` to be added for this site, eh? (:

Comment: Is it something site moderators can do, or is it something that needs the intervention of somebody else?

Comment: @kiamlaluno, no, this is not a moderator function.

Comment: Thank you. For a moment I thought there was a setting for that, and I didn't notice it.